# Integrating Azure Traffic Incident Api in Azure maps

Tags: azure-maps

[azure incidents api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/get-traffic-incident-detail?tabs=HTTP)

how can i integrate this in azure maps.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using one of the Azure Maps SDK's this API is already has a built in experience.

For Web: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-show-traffic
For Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-show-traffic-android?pivots=programming-language-java-android
For iOS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/show-traffic-data-map-ios-sdk

In all three SDK's you set the maps traffic options and set the `incidents` option to `true`.

If you want to create a custom UI for incident's and/or have more control over what gets displayed, you can load the vector tile service in directly like these sample:

https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=vector-tile-bubble-layer

https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=vector-tile-heat-map